# How to write the below query in snowflake sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sybase

```
WHILE (SELECT AVG(unit_price) FROM Products) < 30 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Products
    WHERE UnitPrice = MAX(UnitPrice)
    IF ( SELECT MAX(UnitPrice) FROM Products ) < 50 
        BREAK
END
```

We need to convert Sybase SQL query to snowflake sql query. Now above query need to be converted as snowflake sql.

Comment: What have you tried? You should at least tried something from your side.

Comment: Did you even try to run this in snowflake?

Comment: I have tried in snowflake. I am getting below error.                      
 SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'WHILE'

Comment: You are missing part of the while statement.  You need to End While